# Unable to find Pokémon GO on Google Play Store

Tags: pokemon-go

So, when Pokémon GO was announced, I was super excited because I am a huge Pokémon fan.

When it was released in my country I went to the Google Play store and searched for it, but it didn't show up. My friends (who also have Samsung phones) said they got it. How can I get it?

Comment: Are you sure your model of Samsung is compatible? Do you have a compatible version of Android installed? Check the [supported devices page](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices) on the Niantic site.

Comment: If you have a Galaxy S3 or worse you can't get it from the play store. They're just not good enough to run the game.

Answer (score 2):

Check and make sure your device and OS are compatible. If you're logged in to your google account on your desktop computer and have it synced with your Android phone, you can go to the [Pokemon Go Play Store page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo) and see if it's compatible or not.

When searching from Google Play Store on your phone, incompatible apps generally don't show up.

Answer (score -1):

first check if your country is in the launch list of the game...if doesn't than try to download it from the third party sites...

if you are in the country list than try to check your phones location (i.e,region,country)..and also check for the google play store's as well..
if this is the issue than google it..it will guide you..

second check the android version of your device it must be android 4.4 and up..

hope this help..!!

Comment: Downloading the game from a third party site and side loading it onto your phone is not recommended. Not only is it considered cheating, but it could leave your vulnerable to malware and viruses!

Comment: True one but you must play the gamble if you are a die-hard fan of it. anyway this are the possible ways for it. thanks for my missing part @Kwuz